# Do I need to update statistics after Truncating and Re-Populating a table

Tags: sql-server

As part of a maintenance process (MS SQL Server 2008), we need to truncate and then re-populate some tables. The majority of the data in the re-populated tables  will be the same as before they are truncated (>95%). This is done on an nightly basis.

After doing the re-population, is it necessary to Update the statistics on the table or would it be okay to do this less regularly to take account of the new/updated data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by statistics?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate Table and UPDATE Statistics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730232/truncate-table-and-update-statistics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database

NO need to Update statistics it updates automatically

```
CREATE TABLE T
    (
        number   integer NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO t

SELECT  distinct number  
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE number < 500

select 1 from t where number = 1

  DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS (N'T', number) WITH STAT_HEADER, HISTOGRAM

  truncate table t




insert  into t
SELECT  distinct number  
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE number > 500;

select 1 from t where number > 1  and number <500

  DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS (N'T', number) WITH STAT_HEADER, HISTOGRAM
```

EDIT* Auto Update on database level should be ON(Which is on by Default)

Comment: what if select name, is_auto_update_stats_on from sys.databases where name = 'yourdb'
return 0?

Comment: thanks i have edited the answer